# Handling Large Payloads in CosmosDB with Azure Durable Functions

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-durable-functions

We have encountered an issue with a function responsible for writing data chunks into CosmosDB. The problem arises when one of the items within these chunks exceeds 2MB in size, resulting in the following exception:

```bash
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Message: {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}
```

To mitigate this issue, we initially attempted to estimate the payload size using sys.getsizeof, but this approach proved ineffective. Consequently, we are exploring alternative solutions to address this specific payload size problem. One possible approach is to handle the oversized payload individually and take appropriate action, such as sending it to a queue or implementing a similar strategy.

##### The problem

The core issue we are facing is that our exception handling mechanism is not functioning as expected. Not even the logging within the exception handler nor the logging in the orchestrator's exception clause is being triggered. We are using retry policies for error handling; however, for this particular scenario, they appear to be ineffective since the payload size remains constant.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```py
  # activity
  
  try:
    entitiesCollection.set(entities_document_list)
    classificationsCollection.set(classifications_document_list)
    relatedAssetsCollection.set(related_assets_document_list)
    lineageCollection.set(lineage_document_list)

  except Exception as err:
      logging.error(f"Saving to CosmosDB failed with error - {err}")
```

Comment: Having super-large documents that occasionally exceed max document size is an *anti-pattern*. I suggest editing to give a concrete example of your general document schema - I’m guessing you have some unbounded arrays? (Another anti-pattern, since they can grow infinitely). If you’re hitting such a case, there’s really no way to resolve, other than refactoring your data model.

Comment: The data source is actually MS Purview, which in theory should only have assets no bigger than 2MB as well. However the problem lies in the lineage, somehow this asset has over 20K of them. Every other asset does not present the same problem. Interestingly, when saved on disk, this asset has around 400KB.

Comment: @DavidMakogon would you have any inputs? Also, besides the request size exception, we're getting a few others, and not being able to properly handle them.